# Will the "count limit" expression of a for-loop be evaluated only once, or on each iteration?

Tags: java, loops, methods, for-loop, call

If I invoke a method within a loop's conditional statement, will it be called with each loop iteration?

For example:

```
for( int i = 0; i <= expensiveComputation(); i++ ) {
    // Do something.
}
```

Will I be performing `expensiveComputation()` on each iteration? Or will the result of `expensiveComputation()` be stored and used in each iteration at the same time the loop variable is initialised?

Should I instead re-write it to that:

```
int max = expensiveComputation();
for ( int i = 0; i <= max; i++ ) {
    // Do something.
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It will be invoked on each iteration, unless the compiler/optimizer decides that it has no side effects and can possibly eliminate the call as an optimization.

I mean, the compiler can't just blindly store the value because a function in java, unlike a mathematical function, can have not only a return value, but also such side effects as printing something to some stream or changing some global state etc.

There is also another reason why the compiler can't omit the call each iteration. The fact that your function doesn't take any arguments does not mean that it will necessarily return the same value each time. It can, for example, input a number from a stream and return it, or it can randomly generate a number.

So the compiler needs to be extremely careful before it can safely eliminate the calls. So, if the function is expensive, you should definitely pre-store its value.

Comment: Thanks, I never thought of it that way! ;)

Comment: Thinking along the same lines, would you say that: for( Object obj : getAllObjects() ) {} would re-grab a new collection with each iteration?

Comment: @BARNZ: Hmm.. That's different. A foreach loop is indeed different. I suppose that in case of a foreach loop it won't do it every iteration. But I am not sure

Comment: The "desugared" version of the enhanced for statement is given in [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2), and shows that it does *not* evaluate the expression on each iteration: the `Expression` (in this case `getAllObjects()`) only appears in the `ForInit` part of the equivalent basic for loop, which is only evaluated once.

Answer (score 2):

The second option is better specially if the computation does not require to be calculated at each iteration

If you suppose your loop is n length and you computation is O(n).

 With the first solution, the complexity is **O(n<sup>2</sup>)** while the other is **O(2n)**

Answer (score 2):

<strike>It may or may not be called on each iteration, depending on what bytecode the compiler feels like emitting.</strike> Most likely it will in fact be called each time.

If you want to *ensure* that it is not invoked on each iteration, then use the `int max = ...` version.

Why not simply test it yourself?

Comment: Actually, the Java compiler here has not that much choice. If any optimization occurs, than on runtime by the Hotspot JIT-compiler.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you should cache your result in these situations, to ensure better performance.